# system function output with Chinese chars

Tags: functions, encoding

I want to run shell command with system function and the command output has some Chinese chars.

```
echo system('svn status')
```

But I got incorrect encoding output like this:

```
svn:  ?\232?\173?\166?\229?\145?\138: W155007: ?\226?\128?\156/Users/mfw?\226?\128?\157?\228?\184?\141?\230?\152?\175?\229?\183?\165?\228?\189?\156?\229?\137?\175?\230?\156?\172
```

And the correct output is:

```
svn:  警告: W155007: “/Users/mfw”不是工作副本
```

So How can I get Chinese chars output correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: Only macvim has this problem

Comment: Can you try this command `:version` and put the output here?

Comment: OK, thank you @SibiCoder and the output is :

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Apr 23 2014 23:55:02)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-258
Compiled by Douglas Drumond <drumond.douglas@gmail.com>

Comment: We need to check the encoding of shell and vim. In vim, give `:set encoding`, `:set fileencoding`, `:set termencoding` and paste the output here. If all three are utf-8 or a CJK supported encoding, problem is not with vim.   For shell: give `svn status` in shell and check whether you are getting the output as expected. If not, shell has a problem with encoding support.

Comment: Thank you @SibiCoder for your response. Yesterday I uninstall macports on my mac, and my svn message became English. I cannot get the incorrect Chinese message now.

set encoding: utf-8
set fileencoding: ''(new tab and not file open)
set termencoding: utf-8

And svn status in shell is correct.

Comment: So, you found the answer? Post it here :)